# How can I compile OpenCL kernels written in OpenCL-C++?

Tags: c++, opencl, jit

I would love to be able to use C++ in my OpenCL kernels.

However, the OpenCL 3.0 host-side API documentation, Section 5.8.1, [says](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/specs/3.0-unified/html/OpenCL_API.html#_creating_program_objects):

> **5.8.1. Creating Program Objects**
>
> To creates a program object for a context and load source code into that object, call the function
>
> ```
> cl_program clCreateProgramWithSource(
>     cl_context context,
>     cl_uint count,
>     const char** strings,
>     const size_t* lengths,
>     cl_int* errcode_ret);
> ```

... snip ...

> The source code specified by strings is either an OpenCL C program
> source, header or implementation-defined source for custom devices
> that support an online compiler. OpenCL C++ is not supported as an
> online-compiled kernel language through this interface.

So how *am* I supposed to compile OpenCL C++ kernel code? I can't find another API function that takes that as input.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr: That *is* how you compile OpenCL-C++ code, but it only works under certain conditions.**

Details:

Support for JIT compilation of OpenCL-C++ programs is an OpenCL extension, and is not supported/provided for by the core API.

If an OpenCL implementation support the [`cl_ext_cxx_for_opencl` extension](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/extensions/ext/cl_ext_cxx_for_opencl.html), then:

You start by querying your device to determine whether the compiler for that specific device supports OpenCL C++. Use the `CL_DEVICE_CXX_FOR_OPENCL_NUMERIC_VERSION_EXT` value for the `cl_device_info` code.

Assuming the device compiler does support OpenCL C++, you then *can* pass OpenCL code to `clCreateProgramWithSource()`. But you will have to explicitly have`-cl-std=CLC++` as part of the command-line arguments to  `clCompileProgram()` / `clBuildProgram()`, to actually have the compiler interpret your programs as OpenCL C++.

Within your OpenCL-C++ program, the value of the `__OPENCL_CPP_VERSION__`  is supposed to agree with the value of the `CL_DEVICE_CXX_FOR_OPENCL_NUMERIC_VERSION_EXT` device property on the host side.